# Mostrar un valor y su posición en java

Tags: java, array

Tengo este algoritmo:

```
NE= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Digite numero de estudiantes"));
int j[]= new int [NE];

for (int k = 0; k < NE; k++) {

    j[k] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Digite nota del estudiante "+(k+1)));

    if (j[k]>NM) {
        NM = j[k];
    }else{
        NMI = j[k];
    }
}

for (int k = 0; k < NE; k++) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La mas alta es: "+NM+" esta en la posición:"+j[k]+"\n"+
    "La nota mas baja es: "+NMI+" esta en la posición: "+j[k]);
}
```

El algoritmo me muestra las notas deseadas, pero no me muestra la posición en la que se encuentran.

Comment: k es la posición que tienen en el array, eso no te sirve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu algoritmo esta mal. No hace lo que vos decis..

```
for (int k = 0; k < NE; k++) {
    j[k] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Digite nota del estudiante "+(k+1)));
    if (j[k]>NM) {
        NM = j[k];
    }else{
        NMI = j[k];
    }
}
```

Fijate que el if verifica si la nota recien ingresada es mayor a la que figuraba como mayor.. si es asi, la pone como mayor..

El problema es el else.. si no es mayor, **no necesariamente** es la menor..

fijate que si ingresas valores asi:

```
8
9
4
5
```

Te queda como mayor el 9.. y como menor el 5.. cuando deberia ser el 4 ;)

no es if...else lo que necesitas.. son dos if...

Y despues.. cuando buscas la posicion en el vector, es recorrer el vector y compararar....

```
for (int k = 0; k < NE; k++) {
```

Aca.. deberias compara si j[k] es igual a NM o NMI, y mostrar el cartel que corresponda ;)

```
if (j[k] == NM) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La mas alta es: "+NM+" esta en la posición:"+k+"\n"
}
```

Fijate, que para mostrar la posicion, mostras k, no j[k]

Comment: al momento de comparar debe estar dentro del for?